# jQuery Mobile - Thumbnail on listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I show image/thumbnail in a jQuery Mobile listview widget but only an iPhone, not on an iPad? Is it as simple as putting some magic CSS class or data- attribute or does it involve media queries and such?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on `userAgent` whether it returns `iPad`, remove `img` from *listview*.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainercreate", function () {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match("iPad") != null) {
      $(document).on("listviewcreate", function () {
          $(".ui-li-has-thumb", this)
              .find("img")
              .remove()
              .end()
              .removeClass("ui-li-has-thumb");
      });
  }
});
```

This will remove both `img` and `ui-li-has-thumb` class from `li` whenever a *listview* is created. I have used `pagecontainercreate` because it fires one time only.